# Assign attributes when another is changed

Tags: python

I have a Python Shape class with an attribute called datum. It is a list with two numbers, x and y.

If I do

```
my_shape = Shape()
```

Then the datum is given default value: [0,0]
Now, I want to reassign the datum by doing:

```
my_shape.datum = [3,2]
```

then my datum is now assigned that list.

But I also have attributes x and y. How do I make x and y automatically update to become the first and second item of the datum list?

I put this in the **init**

```
self.x = self.datum[0]
self.y = self.datum[1]
```

But that only assigns x and y to the initialized values and I can't figure out how to update when self.datum updates.

I'm sorry if this is confusing. Thank you so much for helping this newbie.

-Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define `x` and `y` as [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
@property
def x(self):
    return self.datum[0]

@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    self.datum[0] = value

@property
def y(self):
    return self.datum[1]

@y.setter
def y(self, value):
    self.datum[1] = value
```

This way, `x` and `y` are not attributes (and thus the data is stored only once in the `datum`), but stay usable as such (i.e.: `my_shape.x` and `my_shape.y` works as expected).

Comment: Right sorry, copy paste is the enemy... :)

Comment: Thank you, icecrime. This helps a lot.